# If $f$ is increasing, then $g \ge 0$ and $\int_a^b g \mathrm d \lambda \le f(b)-f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure, monotone-functions

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define $g:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
g(x) :=
\begin{cases}
f^{\prime}(x) & \text{if } f \text { differentiable at } x \in (a, b),\\
0 & \text {otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $g$ [is Borel measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607083/the-derivative-defined-a-e-is-borel-measurable). Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$. I would like to prove below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $f$ is increasing, then $g \ge 0$ and $\int_a^b g \mathrm d \lambda \le f(b)-f(a)$.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** It's clear that $g \ge 0$. Let
$$
g_n(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}} & \text{if } f \text { differentiable at } x \in [a, b-\frac{1}{n}], \\
0 & \text {otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $g_n \to g$ **everywhere**. Because $f$ is [differentiable $\lambda$-a.e.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606963/a-proof-that-a-monotonic-function-is-differentiable-almost-everywhere), we get
$$
g_n =\frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}} \quad \text{for } \lambda \text{-a.e. } x \in \left [a, b-\frac{1}{n} \right].
$$

By Fatou's lemma,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b g \mathrm d \lambda &\le \liminf_n \int_a^b g_n \mathrm d \lambda  \\
&= \liminf_n \int_a^{b-1/n} g_n \mathrm d \lambda  \\
&= \liminf_n n \left [ \int_{a+1/n}^b f \mathrm d \lambda - \int_{a}^{b-1/n} f \mathrm d \lambda\right ]  \\
&= \liminf_n n \left [ \int_{b-1/n}^b f \mathrm d \lambda - \int_{a}^{a+1/n} f \mathrm d \lambda \right ] \\
&\le \liminf_n n \left [ \frac{f(b)}{n}- \frac{f(a)}{n} \right ] \text{ because } f \text{ is increasing} \\
&= f(b)-f(a).
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: It seems that this follows from the fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integral calculus. For subintervals $[c,d]$ such that $f$ is absolutely continuous, $\int_c^d f'(t)\ \mathsf dt=f(d)-f(c)$, and elsewhere the integrand is zero.