# The $\lambda$-integrability of the derivative of a function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f$ its [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable). Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$. I would like to prove below properties for functions of bounded variation, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $f$ is of bounded variation, then
>
> 1. $f$ is differentiable $\lambda$-a.e.,
> 2. The function
>    $$
>    g(x) :=
>    \begin{cases}
>    f^{\prime}(x) & \text{if } f \text { differentiable at } x \in (a, b),\\
>    0 & \text {otherwise}.
>    \end{cases}
>    $$
>    is [$\lambda$-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space) such that $\int_a^b |g| \mathrm d \lambda \leq \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f$.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof**

- By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607181/a-characterization-of-functions-of-bounded-variation) lemma, there exist increasing functions $f_1, f_2:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=f_1-$ $f_2$ and
  $$
  \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f = f_1(b)-f_1(a)+f_2(b)-f_2(a).
  $$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606963/a-proof-that-a-monotonic-function-is-differentiable-almost-everywhere) lemma, $f_1, f_2$ are differentiable $\lambda$-a.e. Claim (1.) then follows.

- Let
  $$
  g_1(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
  f_1^{\prime}(x) & \text{if } f_1 \text { differentiable at } x \in (a, b),\\
  0 & \text {otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
  $$
  and
  $$
  g_2(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
  f_2^{\prime}(x) & \text{if } f_2 \text { differentiable at } x \in (a, b),\\
  0 & \text {otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
  $$

I [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607083/the-derivative-defined-a-e-is-borel-measurable) that $g, g_1, g_2$ are Borel measurable. So $g, g_1, g_2$ are [$\lambda$-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1). I [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609938/if-f-is-increasing-then-g-ge-0-and-int-ab-g-mathrm-d-lambda-le-fb) that $g_1, g_2 \ge 0$ and
$$
\int_a^b g_1 \mathrm d \lambda \le f_1(b)-f_1(a)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\int_a^b g_2 \mathrm d \lambda \le f_2(b)-f_2(a).
$$

Notice that $g=g_1-g_2$ $\lambda$-a.e., so
$$
\int_a^b |g| \mathrm d \lambda \le \int_a^b |g_1| \mathrm d \lambda + \int_a^b |g_2| \mathrm d \lambda = (f_1(b)-f_1(a))+(f_2(b)-f_2(a)) = \operatorname{Var}_{[a, b]} f < \infty.
$$

This completes the proof.