# If $f$ is absolutely continuous and $f' = 0$ $\lambda$-a.e., then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$ and $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb R$. I would like to prove below property of an absolutely continuous function, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $f$ is [absolutely continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099894/the-definition-of-absolute-continuous-function/4100439#4100439) and $f' = 0$ $\lambda$-a.e., then $f$ is constant.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Fix $c \in [a, b]$. We want to prove that $f(c)= f(a)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is $\delta>0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(y_{i})-f(x_i)| < \varepsilon$ for every finite collection of pairwise disjoint subintervals $\{[x_i, y_i] : i=1, \ldots, n\}$ of $[a, b]$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-x_i) <\delta$.

Let $D := \{x\in [a, c] : f'(x)=0\}$. For each $x \in D$, there is an interval $[a_x, c_x] \subset [a, c]$ with arbitrarily small length such that $x \in [a_x, c_x]$ and $|f(c_x)-f(a_x)| \le \varepsilon (c_x-a_x)$. Then $\{[a_x, c_x] : x \in D\}$ is a Vitali cover of $D$. By Vitali's covering [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606604/a-proof-of-vitalis-covering-theorem), there is a finite subcollection $\{[a_i, c_i] : i=1, \ldots, n\}$ of pairwise disjoint intervals such that
$$
\lambda \bigg ( D \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i, c_i] \bigg ) < \delta.
$$

Because $\lambda ([a, c] \setminus D)=0$, we get
$$
\lambda \bigg ( [a, c] \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i, c_i] \bigg ) < \delta.
$$

WLOG, we assume
$$
a =: c_0 \le a_1 \le c_1 \le a_2 \le c_2 \le \cdots \le a_n \le c_n \le a_{n+1} :=c.
$$

Let
$$
(x_1, y_1) := (c_0, a_1), (x_2, y_2) := (c_1, a_2), \ldots, (x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}) := (c_n, a_{n+1}).
$$

Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (y_i-x_i) = \lambda \bigg ( [a, c] \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i, c_i] \bigg ) < \delta.
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
|f(c)-f(a)| &\le \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} |f(y_{i}) - f(x_i)| + \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(c_{i}) - f(a_i)| \\
&\le\varepsilon + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \varepsilon (c_{i} - a_i)  \\
&\le \varepsilon (1 + c-a).
\end{align}
$$

We take the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ and obtain the result.

Comment: I think we can use FTC to draw the conclution much easily. Or are you proving this before FTC?

Comment: @Riemann FTU applies to functions differentiable *everywhere*. However, in my case $f$ is differentiable only $\lambda$-a.e. Could you explain how to use FTC?

Comment: It is standard result that for absolutely continuous functions FTC applies. In integrating the value of function on a null set does not matter, so we may give arbitrary value to $f'$ where it is undefined and integrate on $[a, x]$. In this sense we simply say $f(c)-f(a) = \int_a^c f'(x)d\lambda.$

Comment: @Riemann You're right. This thread is a preparation for the version FTC with Lebesgue-integrable functions.

Comment: @Riemann This standard result is non-trivial and is usually called Rademacher's Theorem